# "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
string JDate = "21/01/2016 3:47 PM";
```

when I convert `jDate` to `DateTime`, An error Occurred

```
DateTime journeyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(JDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `TT` for the `PM`.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `tt` form PM as @SLaks said to convert the `string` to `DateTime`

```
string JDate = "21/01/2016 3:47 PM"; 
DateTime journeyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(JDate, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding tt will fix the issue.

"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt"